# Flutter: Expanded vs Flexible

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

I've used both `Expanded` and `Flexible` widgets and they both seem to work the same.

What is the difference between Expanded and Flexible?

Answer (score 256, accepted):

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(),
  body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          buildExpanded(),
          buildFlexible(),
        ],
      ),
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          buildExpanded(),
          buildExpanded(),
        ],
      ),
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          buildFlexible(),
          buildFlexible(),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

[image]

Comment: Flexible takes only the needed space, and Expanded takes all available space, respecting the `flex` factor.  See [the docs of the `Expanded` widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) for more info.

Comment: Flexible and Container both take the needed space.

Comment: What confused me is the behaviour is the same when a container is the child of `Flexible` or `Expanded`. This is because `Containers with no children try to be as big as possible` [source](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html). So the container makes Flexible look like its forcing container to be big, but actually its the containers true desire, the flexible just lets it be, whereas Expanded forces the container to be big.

Comment: `Flexible` widget can use the `fit` property which is `FlexBox.loose` by default and you can set it to `FlexBox.tight` for similar behavior of `Expanded` widget

Answer (score 199):

`Expanded` is just a shorthand for `Flexible`

Using `Expanded` this way:

```
Expanded(
  child: Foo(),
);
```

is strictly equivalent to:

```
Flexible(
  fit: FlexFit.tight,
  child: Foo(),
);
```

---

You may want to use `Flexible` over `Expanded` when you want a different `fit`, useful in some responsive layouts.

The difference between `FlexFit.tight` and `FlexFit.loose` is that `loose` will allow its child to have a maximum size while `tight` forces that child to fill all the available space.

Comment: doesn't `Maximum size` and `Available space` mean the same thing here?

Comment: No, by maximumsize I meant something like having as child of Flexible a ConstrainedBox with a maxHeight inside a Column

Comment: In easy words, `Flexible.tight` will force the children to take up the available entire space and `Flexible.loose` will let the children do what they want. Some children might take up the entire space and some not, depending what their types are.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad meant `FlexFit.tight` and `FlexFit.loose` above.

Answer (score 115):

Widget under `Flexible` are by default **WRAP_CONTENT** although you can change it using parameter `fit`.

Widget under `Expanded` is **MATCH_PARENT** you can change it using `flex`.

Comment: Even though Flexible seems like WRAP_CONTENT, we use Align inside Flexible for an alignment in the available space.

Comment: I searched everywhere and also tried the CHATGPT but only you could make me understand it in a crystal clear way. Thanks, my man!!

Answer (score 29):

`Expanded` - it is `Flexible` with set fit

```
class Expanded extends Flexible {
    const Expanded({
        Key key,
        int flex = 1,
        @required Widget child,
    }) : super(
        key: key, 
        flex: flex, 
        fit: FlexFit.tight, 
        child: child
    );
}
```

Answer (score 20):

You may use **Flexible** to resize the widgets in *rows* and *columns*. It's mainly used to adjust the space of the different child widgets while keeping the relation with their parent widgets.

Meanwhile, **Expanded** changes the constraints sent to the children of *rows* and *columns*; it helps to fill the available spaces there. Therefore, when you wrap your child in an Expanded widget it fills up the empty spaces.

Providing these videos from the *Flutter's Official YouTube channel* just to help out people, who might look for this in the upcoming future...

1. **[Expanded:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_rnZaagadyo&feature=youtu.be)**
2. **[Flexible:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CI7x0mAZiY0)**

Answer (score 20):

Expanded() is nothing more than Flexible() with

`Flexible (fit: FlexFit.tight) = Expanded()`

but, Flexible uses `fit :FlexFit.loose` by default.

**FlexFit.tight** = Wants to fit tight into parent taking as much space as possible.

**FlexFit.loose** = Wants to fit loose into parent taking as little space as possible for itself.

Answer (score 6):

**Expanded** changes the constraints of a child widget so it fills any empty space. Expanded widget is a specialised Flexible widget with a set fit  - Flexible(fit: FlexFit.tight. Expanded widgets also have a flex property.

**Flexible** makes the child widget flexible and resizable. You can add the flex or fit property to adjust the size and spacing.

Flexible fit properties include:

- FlexFit.loose - The widget’s preferred size is used. (Default)
- FlexFit.tight - Forces the widget to fill all of its extra space.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Flexible** default will share the available space of the parent widget, but will **NOT** force the child to fit the space.

**Expanded** will share the available space of the parent widget, and force the child widget to change its width/height to **fill the available space**.

In fact, `Expanded` extends `Flexible`, which is a `Flexible` with `FlexFit.tight`. See the [official document](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html).

Here is a `Container` widget and three `Flexible` Widgets(`flex = 1, fit = FlexFit.loose`) in a row. We can see that the three flexible widgets share the same `maxWidth` (1/3 of the available screen width), and the blue one wants bigger than it, and the others want smaller. But as we can see, the blue guy has `maxWidth` as its width and the other widgets' width just fit their content.

[image: Flexible default will share the available space of the parent widget, but will NOT force the child to fit the space.]

Here is the code of the image above up:

```
        Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [
            Container(
                color: Colors.teal,
                child: Text(
                  'Container Text ',
                )),
            Flexible(
              child: Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: Text(' Text.Flexible Text.Flexible Text.Flexible.')),
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: Container(
                  color: Colors.yellow, child: Text('Flexible Text.')),
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: Container(
                  color: Colors.lightGreen, child: Text('Flexible.')),
            ),
          ],
        )
```

Answer (score 3):

The Expanded widget in flutter is shorthand of Flexible with the default fit of FlexFit.tight. A Flexible widget plays a very important part in making a responsive app. This will make the app looks and feels the same across multiple device sizes. But if one wants just basic filling up of spaces by widgets, then you can use Expanded.

https://flutteragency.com/flexible-widget-in-flutter/
This blog explains the main difference between the the two widget which are sometimes confusing to others...

Answer (score 1):

here is the best example of expanded vs flexible

```
Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Flexible(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.grey,
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: 6,
                  itemBuilder: (context,index){
                    return ListTile(title: Text('$index'),);
                  }),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    )
```

flexible will take as much space as needed while expanded will occupy as maximum as it can..

to see the difference replace flexible with expand widget..it will occupy all possible space...