# Right overflowed by 23 pixels in flutter listview

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I created a listview But it shows **OVERFLOWED BY PIXELS ERROR**

Here is the listview for you

```
return ListView.builder(

      itemCount: titles.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Card(
            elevation: 50,
            child: InkWell(


              splashColor: Colors.green,
              highlightColor: Colors.red,
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[


              Container(


                height: 100.0,
                  width:50.0,

                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient:LinearGradientStyle.linearGradient(
                        orientation:LinearGradientStyle.ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL,
                        gradientType: LinearGradientStyle.GRADIENT_TYPE_AMIN
                    )
                ),),

                  Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: Text(
                        numbers[index],
                      )),


                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: GradientText((titles[index]),
                      gradient:gradient,

                      style:TextStyle(fontSize:20.0,fontWeight:FontWeight.bold, ),
                    ),
                    //Text(titles[index]),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              onTap: () => onTaps[index](),
            ));
      });
```

**If you need more code please comment** ...

Instead of Overflow error It should come to 2nd line of the list.If you have any solution then please help me....

Comment: You can maybe try the [wrap widget](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5iw2SeFx2M)

Comment: In this case, I would highly recommend you to use ListTile: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l8dj0yPBvgQ
It will make your code looks much cleaner and avoid this problems.

Comment: @tinus jackson do you know any method to use wrap widget in this case. i tried using but error appears in the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ListView.builder(

      itemCount: 1,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Card(
            elevation: 50,
            child: InkWell(


              splashColor: Colors.green,
              highlightColor: Colors.red,
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[


              Container(


                height: 100.0,
                  width:50.0,

                ),

                  Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: Text(
                        "numbers[index]",
                      )),


                  Flexible(
                                      child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: Text("GradientText"*30,

                        style:TextStyle(fontSize:20.0,fontWeight:FontWeight.bold, ),
                      ),
                      //Text(titles[index]),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              onTap: () {},
            ));
      }),
```

Use Flexible widget like parent which widget has overflow

Comment: Thank you it helped me.How can I wrap it with WRAP widget instead of using flexible as parent

Comment: Wrap widget has children property instead of child property. Thats why flexible is better for your situation.

Comment: I wrapped using children but error appeared.then I used your solution to solve this

Comment: You could use expanded, flexible widgets inside of Row and Column widgets. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52645944/flutter-expanded-vs-flexible It could teach somethings to you to learn how to design at flutter

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with **DropdownButton**. I was trying to create a dropdown for questions and answers, for that I had to create **DropdownButton for a custom model**.

My life was saved by **`isExpanded: true,`**

```
List<Question> questions;

   Widget buildDropDown() {
    return DropdownButton<Question>(
      isExpanded: true,
      value: _selectedQuestion,
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      items: questions.map<DropdownMenuItem<Question>>((Question question) {
        return DropdownMenuItem(
          child: Text(
            question.title,
          ),
          value: question,
        );
      }).toList(),
      onChanged: (Question question) {
        setState(() {
          _selectedQuestion = question;
        });
      },
    );
  }

class Question {
  String title;
  String answer;
  int id;

  Question({this.id, this.title});

  void setAnswer(String answer) {
    this.answer = answer;
  }
}
```

[image]