# How can I add a button above a list?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

I tried to add a `RaisedButton` above the `ListView`. I used a `Colum` but I got an error. Can anybody tell me where my mistake is? Thanks in advance!

```
 body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Test"),
            onPressed: null,
          ),
          ListView.builder(
            itemCount: exercises.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, i) {
              return Container(
                child: Text(
                  exercises[i]["text"],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to @Viren answer, You should use **Flexible** instead of Expanded

```
body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Test"),
            onPressed: null,
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: Container(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 5,
                itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                  return Container(
                    child: Text(
                      'jitesh',
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
```

Please find diff [Flutter: Expanded vs Flexible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52645944/flutter-expanded-vs-flexible)

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your listview with Expanded widget.

```
     body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      RaisedButton(
        child: Text("Test"),
        onPressed: null,
      ),
      Expanded( // added widget
     child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: exercises.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
          return Container(
            child: Text(
              exercises[i]["text"],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    ],
  ),
  )
```