# Flutter - Expanded within Flexible

Tags: flutter, layout

My `Row` is composed of two `Flexible` and one of them is a `Column` I would like this column to take all the available vertical space like in my original design.

[image]

[image]

I tried to wrap the `Column` with an `Expanded` but it seems that I can't. I tried the property Flexible.tight of the flexible but it didn't work.

```dart
Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Flexible(
                flex: 2,
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 130.0,
                  width: 130.0,
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35.0),
                    child: CachedNetworkImage(
                      imageUrl: fakeOffers[index].imageUrl,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      placeholder: (context, url) => MC_Shimmer(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Flexible(
                flex: 3,
                fit: FlexFit.tight,
                child: Container(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          fakeOffers[index].title,
                          style: MC_favoriteOfferTitle,
                          maxLines: 2,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          fakeOffers[index].price.toStringAsFixed(0) + ' €',
                          style: MC_priceGradientDetail,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          fakeOffers[index],
                          style: MC_favoriteOfferMeta,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          );
```

Comment: use Expanded instead of Flexible to take up the remain space here is a visual example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52645944/flutter-expanded-vs-flexible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to solve the problem I just set the height of the column to 130.0 as I have a fixed size image.

Answer (score 1):

You need to drop the first `Flexible` (it's fixed size anyway) and convert the second `Flexible` to an `Expanded`. This will let this `Expanded` take up all remaining space. Then, your column needs to take up all available space using `CrossAxisAlignment.stretch`.

Comment: I tried that, but the Column still does not take the whole vertical space :/

Comment: For that, put another `CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` to your root `Row`.

Comment: When I do that, I have the error `BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.`

Comment: If you can provide a working example in codepen, we could make it work. Otherwise it's hard to continue like this.

Comment: My problem only concerns this piece of code :/ Isn't there a theoritical reason of why the column doesn't setrech up ?

Comment: the column itself must be unable to grow any longer. this would be determined by its parent. if I you can create a codepen it would be very easy to fix.

Comment: a great way to debug these issues is to use flutter inspector and see which widget takes up the empty space.