# ListView not scrolling in SingleChildScrollView Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Faced a problem, when adding `SingleChildScrollView` `ListView.builder` does not scroll. What could be the problem and how to fix it? We need to make the ListView scrollable.

**body**

```
 Widget _child(context, Size size) => Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const SizedBox(height: 121),
              const BackStepWidget(text: 'My Poynts'),
              const SizedBox(height: 25),
              PoyntsList(size: size),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
```

**PoyntsList**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) => MediaQuery.removePadding(
        context: context,
        removeTop: true,
        child: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: list.length + 1,
          itemBuilder: (context, index)...
```

Comment: remove this: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()

Comment: Thanks for the help. Works. Tell me, is there a difference Expanded or Flexible?

Comment: See this to understand the difference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52645944/flutter-expanded-vs-flexible

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to remove:

```
physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

you can read about it here : [NeverScrollableScrollPhysics](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NeverScrollableScrollPhysics-class.html)

Answer (score 1):

Please remove singlechildscrollview and simply wrap your PoyntsList with expanded. it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Works. Tell me, is there a difference Expanded or Flexible?

Comment: In your case there were two scrollable widgets in same page. so you have to give neverScrollablePhysics to inner listview. and any physics to outer listview. it will also works.