# Flutter - make button fill the entire container

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test

I am very new to Flutter and I trying to make button fill the entire parent container. I want to create two buttons each of them 50% of device height and 100% width using two `Flexible` with `flex` parameters.

This is What I have:

```
Flexible(
  flex: 1,

  child: Container(
    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 20, 20, 20),
    alignment: Alignment.center,
            
   child: ElevatedButton(
     child:Text('$_counter1'),
     onPressed: _pop1,
    ),

  ),
),
```

Everyday I create websites using CSS and HTML and here in Flutter everything works completly diferent. It's hard to understand the code at the begining. With CSS I cloud only add 100% width and height and done but here I am little bit lost.

This is What I am trying to get:

[image]

Comment: Add UI visuals of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: OK. Done. Check my post.

Answer (score 0):

With flutter, you can use Column, Expanded

```bash
Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(
                color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 20, 20, 20),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  child: Text('Button 1'),
                  onPressed: (){},
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(
                color:  Colors.green,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  child: Text('Button 2'),
                  onPressed: (){},
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could combine Column with cross axis alignment strech to achieve this.
Like so:

```
  Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.grey,
          child: TextButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text(
              'Button 1',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2!.copyWith(
                    color: Colors.grey.shade700,
                  ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.grey.shade700,
          child: TextButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text(
              'Button 2',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2!.copyWith(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
```

Running example:
https://dartpad.dev/?enchanted-pomelo-5708

Answer (score 0):

you are almost right. `Flexible` takes only the needed space. if you want to takes all space available like `100%` then you need to add another properties for `Flexible` :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52646036/12838877

```
Flexible(
  fit: FlexFit.tight,
  child: Foo(),
);
```

or is just shorthand with `Expanded`

```
Flexible(
  fit: FlexFit.tight,
  child: Foo(),
);
```

for comparison : [reff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52904214/12838877)

as you can see, `Flexible` will only take as minimum space needed.
and by default expanded will take 100% available space.

if you want to modify, you just change the `flex` value

[image]