# Flutter UI Text Layout

Tags: flutter, flutter-text

I have a few widgets in a Row. Two text widgets and three custom widgets. For text to wrap into next line it needs to be inside an Expanded but if I use it always pushes search icon all the way to the right but I want it to be right after the word.

Current behaviour:
[image: Behaviour]

So basically I need Text that wraps into two lines if it's too long (so that it doesn't overflow to right) but is not expanded. It should be only as wide as the text. How can I achieve this?

Code:

```dart
Row(
    children: [
        Expanded(
            child: Text('This is very long long text'),
        ),
        SearchIcon(),
        CrossIcon(),
        ZeroIcon(),
    ],
)
```

Comment: Share the code of your current behaviour.

Comment: Search icon is actually next to text you feel the gap because `long` didn't fit completely, so it was pushed to the next line, What layout are you actually looking for ? Could you be precise. I may be of some help then

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your text in "Flexible" instead of Expanded.

**Expanded**
Wants to fit tight into parent taking as much space as possible

**Flexible**
Wants to fit loose into parent taking as little space as possible for itself

For further clarification checkout [Flutter: Expanded vs Flexible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52645944/flutter-expanded-vs-flexible)